# Permanently disable USB automount in headless PI3

Tags: debian

I am running a PI3 headless with Debian 11.8. The PI3 has a HDD permanently connected to a USB port.

This HDD is automatically mounted at boost, and I do not want that. I want to manually mount the HDD.

Permanently disabling USB automount would make the deal.

I have tried with fstab and the noauto option, but unsuccessfully. I have tried editing gsetting parameters, but unsuccessfully, too.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question.

I discovered that although the PI3 was running headless, it was in runlevel 5, which enables automount.

I run the raspbian-config script and chose to boot in console mode in the system parameters. It now boots in runlevel 3. My HDD is no longer automounted at boot. And I still can mount it manually.

Comment: Quick note: "Runlevels" are a vestige of SysV init, which contemporary Debian does not really use, but there is an adaptive layer to convert SysV commands to systemd.  So the difference here is between `graphical.target` and `multi-user.target`; you can get the current setting with `systemctl get-default`.  *However*, pretty sure the automounting is something that's done by the DE (desktop environment), which only happens when someone logs into it, otherwise all that's running is the GUI login -- likely you had autologin set.